# How to do the query every 24 hour and stop it when days>31

Tags: mysql

Hello I have this table and I want to do a query to be done daily 
Select UID from the table where days<31
and update the table set IS_END= 'Y' where days>31 and IS_END ='N'
I have tried to use MYSQL EVENT function but it doesn't work with me.
[MySQL Table photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufQTW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Ahmed and Welcome to SO.

Actually you can do it via MySQL Event. First you need to enable the event scheduler by:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Then you can add an event for your update query:

```
CREATE EVENT 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS '2018-10-29 00:00:00'
DO
UPDATE <table_name> SET IS_END='Y' WHERE days>31 and IS_END='N';
```